# Express an arbitrary rotation matrix in GAP.

Tags: gap

It is well known that the rotation matrix has the formula described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). I wonder how can I express these matrices in GAP with arbitrary rotating angles.

Edit:

1. Dear Max Horn, thank you for your comments. But based on the description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

[image]

I think your code snippet should be written as follows:

```
gap> n:=5;z:=E(n);a:=RealPart(z);b:=ImaginaryPart(z);
5
E(5)
1/2*E(5)+1/2*E(5)^4
1/2*E(20)-1/2*E(20)^9
gap> M:=[[a,-b],[b,a]];
[ [ 1/2*E(5)+1/2*E(5)^4, -1/2*E(20)+1/2*E(20)^9 ], [ 1/2*E(20)-1/2*E(20)^9, 1/2*E(5)+1/2*E(5)^4 ] ]
gap> Order(z);
5
gap> Order(M);
5
```

2. As for the problem of "the added factor 4 in the order of the final matrix" represented by `[[b,-a],[a,b]]`, I can only come up with the following interpretation: `[[b,-a],[a,b]]` is an 18-degree rotation, while `[[a,-b],[b,a]]` is a 72-degree rotation as shown by the following test:

```
gap> n:=5;;z:=E(n);;a:=RealPart(z);;b:=ImaginaryPart(z);;
gap> M1:=[[a,-b],[b,a]];;
gap> M2:=[[b,-a],[a,b]];;
gap> Order(z);
5
gap> Order(M1);
5
gap> Order(M2);
20
gap> M2^4=M1;
true
```

Regards,
HZ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GAP - Is it possible to work with symbolic expressions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739899/gap-is-it-possible-to-work-with-symbolic-expressions)

Comment: That comment is for "polynomials and rational functions". In my case, the triangle function is involved. Therefore, I still can't found the corresponding solution.

Comment: the solution provides an example of a matrix with symbolic entries, which is what it sounds like you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what you really want to know. Since your other questions are about group representations, I am assuming you want to know about rotations by "rational" angles. Then you can use primitive roots of unity to describe the matrix entries using [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Here's an example (I'll leave it as an exercise to deal with the added factor 4 in the order of the final matrix)

```
gap> RotMat := function(n)
>    local z, a, b;
>    z:=E(n);
>    a:=RealPart(z);
>    b:=ImaginaryPart(z);
>    return [[a,-b],[b,a]];
>  end;;
gap> M := RotMat(5);
gap> Order(M);
5
gap> Display(M);
[ [     1/2*E(5)+1/2*E(5)^4,  -1/2*E(20)+1/2*E(20)^9 ],
  [   1/2*E(20)-1/2*E(20)^9,     1/2*E(5)+1/2*E(5)^4 ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the trick. My concern is mainly for rotational symmetry of crystallographic group, in this case, the above tip is enough due that there are only 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6 order of rotations are allowed. As for general rotations by "rational" or "irrational" angles, I think it can be dealt with the Floats numbers (https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap19.html), e.g., by the method discussed here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450209/compute-e2-pi-i-3-in-gap/4450239#4450239).

Comment: According to the description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), I think it should be computed like this: ```gap> M:=[[a,-b],[b,a]];; gap> Order(M);
5```.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not useful for algebraic purposes. They do not even form a ring (e.g. floating point addition and multiplication is not associative).

Comment: Also, it's really weird to edit your question by copying most of my answer. And, asking follow up questions this ways is frowned upon.

Comment: Then what's the preferable way to ask follow-up questions?

Comment: 1. Do you mean that the transcendental numbers related algebra must be treated by decomposing them into polynomials represented by algebraic numbers in GAP?
2. According to the descritpion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), I think your statement "floating point addition and multiplication is not associative" should be phrased as "Multiplication is distributive with respect to addition".

Comment: No, my statement is phrased correctly as it is: addition of floating point numbers is not associative. Neither is multiplication. Floating point numbers do not form a ring

Comment: For follow ups, use comments, when it works, or ask new question when comments are not sufficient. Otherwise, first it's not even guaranteed that the author of the answer will notice your question asked in the edited OP; second, a new reader will struggle to read it in a non-sequential order.