# Compute $e^{{-2\pi i}/3}$ in GAP.

Tags: gap

I tried to calculate the following expression in GAP, but failed:

```
gap> E(-3);
Error, E: <n> must be a positive small integer (not the integer -3)
not in any function at *stdin*:49
type 'quit;' to quit to outer loop
```

So, how can I compute the expression like `exp(2πi/-3)` in GAP?

EDIT: Thank you, MathGeek, I figured out the following expression based on your clues:

```
gap> Cos(-2* FLOAT.PI/3);
-0.5
gap> Sin(-2* FLOAT.PI/3);
-0.866025
```

So, `$e^{{2\pi i}/3}$` should be expressed as follows:

```
gap> [Cos(-2* FLOAT.PI/3), Sin(-2* FLOAT.PI/3)];
[ -0.5, -0.866025 ]
```

Regards,
HZ

Comment: Please consult the people who know about this first, as it is a question about the documentation of a piece of software, and not a mathematical question. https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/People/supportgroup.html

Comment: Use Euler's formula to reduce the problem to a positive argument.

Comment: @Peter Do you mean the method I described in the OP currently?

Comment: Basically what I meant. Note that if you have calculated the expression with the positive sign, say $e^{ix}=a+bi$ ($x$ positive real) , then you just have the conugate complex for the negative case : $e^{-ix}=a-bi$. This follows easily from the fact that the cosine is an even function and the sine an odd function.

Comment: But it seems the negative case can't be expressed as the cyclotomic polynomial of positive entries, so GAP can't calculate `E(-3)` directly.

Comment: In short : $e^{-ix}$ for positive real $x$ is just the conjugate complex of $e^{ix}$

Comment: No, using floating point is *not* the same. Floating point numbers are not the same as real numbers. In fact floating point numbers do not even form a mathematical field, as the binary operations on them are not associative. They are also not exact: the values you computed via `Cos` etc. are only approximations of the real values by necessity. As such, these values are useless for e.g. working with representation.

Comment: So, this is why I ask: For the purpose of group representation, can we use only algebraic numbers without involving transcendental numbers to solve all problems?

Comment: For the purpose of representations of *finite* groups, we can always work in a number field, i.e. a finite degree extension of the rationals.

Comment: Do you mean: Polynomial based on E(n) is enough for the ultimate representations of finite groups in theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Euler's formula for this.
$$e^{ix}= cos(x)+isin(x)$$
We can input ${-2\pi}/3$ for $x$ to get the following:
$$e^{{-2\pi i}/3}= cos({-2\pi}/3)+isin({-2\pi}/3)$$
Hopefully these inputs are valid in GAP.